# Error with Generate Scaffold Micropost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm following the http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ From my application directory I run this command but receive the error below. I have searched around but can figure out how to fix.

```
$ rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user_id:integer
```

This is the error:

```
/Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load': /Users/bryonthomas/Code/demo_app/config/routes.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `block in reload_routes!'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `each'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:127:in `reload_routes!'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:120:in `block in routes_reloader'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:52:in `call'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:52:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /Users/bryonthomas/Code/demo_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
from /Users/bryonthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My routes.rb is:

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: You have an error in your routes code (on line 4), please post the code.

Comment: Here is routes.rbDemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  .
  .
  .
end

Comment: Can you edit your post and put the routes in there? This will be more readable.

Comment: Where did you get the dots from? This isn't valid ruby code, I believe there should be something else at this place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in the first line of the error message.

`/config/routes.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)`

Then in your routes file, notice that you have those periods, which do not belong.

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Remove the periods.

```
DemoApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
end
```